# How to create temp password that requires you to make a new one next login?

Tags: 14.04

How do I:
Set a temp password that requires to be changed next log in?

Comment: You  can change it anytime, so why temp password that requires you to make a new one next login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
passwd --expire {user}
```

will force {user} to provide a new password. Also possible

```
chage --lastday 0 {user}
```

And

```
 chage -l {user}
```

will list details about the state of the password for this user.

You do not need a temp password though.